# User profile service failed the logon - Accounts besides domain administrator cannot log on

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller, user-profile

Ok,

Windows Server 2008 DC.  Trying to log on as a user called BESadmin, I discovered an issue.

No one but the domain administrator can log on locally or via terminal services.

Users without log on rights receive the standard "You do not have rights to log on remotely" error.

Once granted log on rights, local or TS, they get:
"User profile service failed the logon" "User profile cannot be loaded"

I was digging about and located a few Vista guides telling me to check out the registry, but these guides seem to be based on profiles that at one point worked.  BESadmin has never successfully logged on to this machine, nor is there a profile in c:\users for this user.

Here are two items that show up in the event log when attempting to log this user on:

1511:

Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.

1500:

Windows cannot log you on because your profile cannot be loaded. Check that you are connected to the network, and that your network is functioning correctly.

DETAIL - Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.

Comment: have you tried logging in as another administrative account?

Comment: Yes indeed, no dice.

Comment: is this the only DC?

Comment: No, it is the only server 2008 DC though.  We're operating at a 2003 level, there are 3 other DCs.

Comment: I'm considering demoting it.  I'm currently researching if that will cause me any weird problems with Exchange 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this happens only with new users or users witch do not have a v2 profile yet. Your default user profile (c:\Users\Default) might have been damaged - try replacing it with a copy off a fresh installation of Windows Server 2008 or Vista.